# Ember JS: collection view not rendered when content binding changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sproutcore-2

Below is an example of my collection view which is supposed to generate a list of people

```
{{view Em.CollectionView itemViewClass="App.PersonView" contentBinding="App.PeopleController"}}
```

When I populate App.PeopleController the first time, this collection view renders fine. However, when I reset PeopleController and populate it again, the collection view does not render. Does anybody know why?

Updated:

Here's how I populate App.PeopleController

```
people.forEach(function(p) {
  _this.pushObject(App.Person.create(p));
})
```

Comment: could you add the code of your PeopleController and how you reset/populate it ? And the code of the App.Personview ?

Comment: Added how I populated PeopleController. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see problems here. I've made a jsfiddle which works : http://jsfiddle.net/h28tg/ .Could you please update it to show us your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you reset PeopleController in the console and repopulate it in the console? You might need to trigger a new runloop to get the collection view to update.

Comment: Yes, I did reset() and ran the loop again to populate it.